# I want to copy the format of one Spreadsheet in google docs do another spreadsheet. Is this possible?

Tags: formatting

I'm working on a feedback system for my math students and have a matrix that shows what points they have gotten on a test.

I have several sheets in this document with one sheet per student. I have also made one spreadsheet per student that i have put in a shared folder on Google Drive where the students only have viewing rights.

What I want to do is copy the entire sheet from my master document to the student's spreadsheet. This is all fine if I use the import range function however with that the formatting doesn't follow.

Is it possible to use a script with the commands `getBackgroundColor()` and `setBackgroundColor()` to transfer the `backgroundcolors` from the master sheet to the students sheet?

I started with something like this:

```
function getColor() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0ApOkn5XcO_GDdFd4SDBaaFpLSEUxXy1vN2pnNHBpYnc");
var ss=sheet.getSheetByName("Student1");
var r=ss.getRange("A1:R34");
var color = ss.getBackgroundColors();
```

That's about as far as I get. Anyone have ideas?